# How do I integrate JNI code into weblogic?

Tags: weblogic, java-native-interface

I am writing an application which will be deployed in weblogic. As part of this application, we are using a third party library which uses JNI. How do I make the .so file available to weblogic?

I tried setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and restarting weblogic with no luck

Answer (score 0):

The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable should be set in the `setWLSEnv.sh` or the `startWLS.sh` scripts.

Can you show us where and how you did that?

Answer (score 0):

You can include the path of the `.so` files for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the `commEnv.sh` . In `<WL_install_dir>/common/bin/commEnv.sh` based on your OS case block you can update with `.so` folder like below

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/vardhan/SOfiles/:${PATCH_LIBPATH}:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Obviously after updating you need restart all the services.